# Manipulate form data then submit with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a scenario where I need to send form data via a `GET` (not a `POST`). I'm submitting the form to the same page as the form is on (form `action="#`).

The problem is that the controller for the site can't handle array data-- it looks for strings or `json` only. So when I have any array data from a row of text boxes that gets sent, I get a 500 error.

I am currently doing something like this:

```
$('#submit').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form.serialize();
    $form.submit();
})
```

But this doesn't get the job done. The URL params look like this:

```
index.php?condition%5b%5d%3dtest
```

How can I access the actual form data and "rewrite" the data to be a valid `json` string for the text box values prior to sending the form?

I could `POST` the data but then I'd need a different route, and I could send the form via ajax but that would be overkill.

Thanks

NOTE: I know how to serialize the data already, as is explained in my code sample. The problem is I want to *replace* the URL params in the default form submission with the newly serialized / `json`-ified versions, and the suggested duplicate question does not address this.

Comment: I'd POST it every day of the week, it's worth adding the route. If you need to get this working, I think we'll need more info about the framework you're building in and/or the code of the form and controller to give you proper recommendations.

Comment: @MikelBitson-- I know, it's not a big deal and I'm probably wasting more time getting this working than it'd take to create a new view / route. More annoyed and curious at this point.

Comment: The 500 error is concerning. I take it you cannot get the actual error from the host? Can you post an example of your HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery)